# Independence of fractional ideal for representation numbers in real quadratic number fields

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals, class-field-theory

Let $K$ be a real quadratic number field of prime discriminant $D$. We define for $\mathfrak a$ being a fractional ideal of $K$, $n \in \mathbb Z$ and $b \in \mathbb N$
$$R(\mathfrak a,n,b) := \# \{ x \in \mathfrak a/b\mathfrak a : N(x)/N(\mathfrak a) \equiv n \pmod b \}.$$
A few facts I discovered:

- Because $D$ is prime, we have a unit of $\varepsilon \in \mathcal O_K$ of negative norm, hence $R(\mathfrak a,n,b)=R(\mathfrak a,-n,b)$.
- For fixed $\mathfrak a$ and $n$ the function $b \mapsto R(\mathfrak a,n,b)$ is multiplicative.
- For fractional ideals $\mathfrak a,\mathfrak b$ of the same ideal class we have $R(\mathfrak a,n,b)=R(\mathfrak b,n,b)$.

**My conjecture:** The value $R(\mathfrak a,n,b)$ does not depend on $\mathfrak a$. Hence, we have $R(\mathfrak a,n,b)=R(\mathfrak b,n,b)$ for all fractional ideals $\mathfrak a,\mathfrak b$.

Any ideas how to prove that? Because of my third fact the statement is only substantial if the class number $h_K>1$.

Comment: Given $\mathfrak{a},b,n$ and $x\in O_K/(b), N(x) = n\bmod b$

find $c\in \mathfrak{a}$ such that $ N(c)/N(\mathfrak{a})=1\bmod b$

then $N(cx)/N(a) = n\bmod b$

Comment: @reuns So this proves the equality for fixed $b$ for all ideals $\mathfrak a$ for which $R(\mathfrak a,1,b) >0$, right?